# Only one for loop runs in python

Tags: python

When I put 'HelLO' into this code, it should put out 10, but only puts out 5, why?

The programme is meant to add 5 to the score if a word contains a lower case letter, and another if it contains a upper case letter. However, it only has to have at least one in for the score to be added. HellO has both uppercase and lowercase letters, so should add up to 10.

```
capitals="A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
         "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U",
         "V","W","X","Y","Z"  
characters="a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j",
           "k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u",
           "v","w","x","y","z"
word=raw_input("word please")
score=0

for i in range(0,len(word)):
    a=i

for i in range(0,26):
    if word[a]==characters[i]:
        score=score+5
        break

for i in range(0,26):
    if word[a]==capitals[i]:
        score=score+5
        break

print score
```

Comment: explain your question a bit more

Comment: `a` does not get hot-updated. No matter how many times you assign it a new value,cit will only hold one – the last one.

Comment: Is `'O'` both a capital *and* lowercase...?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it easier to see the problem

Comment: `a` is 4; `word[a]` is `'O'`; `'O'` is in `capitals` but not in `characters`; so score is 5.

Answer (score 3):

After the execution of the loop `for i in range(0,len(word)): a=i` the value of `a` becomes `len(word)-1` (in your case, 4) and never changes again. Here's what you are looking for:

```
import string
score = 0
# Does the string have at least one uppercase char?
if set(string.ascii_uppercase) & set(word):
    score += 5
# Does the string have at least one lowercase char?
if set(string.ascii_lowercase) & set(word):
    score += 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is have nested for loops. so that you check each letter in `word` to see if it meets the criteria.

but in that case you would also need to have a flag or some indication that a capital or lower case letter has been found so you don't double count.

Here are some changes you can make to get to your intended answer, however I'd also add that you there are a couple of other improvements you could make to this code for simplification/efficiency.

- look into using the `in` functionality of lists: like `letter in capitals`
- look into `.upper()` functionality built into all strings
- list comprehensions

Anyways here is a fix that gets to your intended functionality.

```
capitals="A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"       
characters="a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"
word=raw_input("word please")
score=0

capital_found = False
lower_found = False

for i in range(0,len(word)):
    a=i

    if not lower_found:

        for i in range(0,26):
            if word[a]==characters[i]:
                score=score+5
                lower_found = True
                break

    if not capital_found:

        for i in range(0,26):
            if word[a]==capitals[i]:
                score=score+5
                capital_found = True
                break

print score
```